# Походження слова "отець"

Tags: етимологія

Синоніми до слова ["батько"](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE) із словника синонімів

> **БА́ТЬКО** (чоловік стосовно своїх дітей), **ТА́ТО** *розм.*, **БА́ТЯ** *розм.
>   рідко,* **ОТЕ́ЦЬ** *уроч., діал.*, **НЯ́НЬО** *діал.*, **НЯ́НЬО** *діал.*, **НЯ́НЬКО** *діал.*; **ПАНОТЕ́ЦЬ** *заст.* (з повагою)

[image: батько]

Яке походження має слово **"отець"**. Мені здається, що воно скальковане з російської **"отец"** в значені **"священик".**

Comment: Родич-запитання: [**Батьківщина** і **вітчизна**. Чому два слова, і звідки друге?](/q/835/585)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Згідно до [Етимологічного словника української мови](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) (том 4, 232 сторінка) та [статті](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE) на Вікіпедії слово "отець" походить від праслов'янського "otьcь", що є ранішою формою "otьkъ", яка утворена від "otъ" (батько). Зміна суфікса -ьkъ на -ьcь пояснюється дією третьої палаталізації. Праслов'янське "otъ" виводять від праіндоєвропейського "átta".

І так ви праві, російське слово "отец" має спільні корені із українським "отець" (див. [етимологію слова](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%86) "отец").

Але все ж наше "отець" не буде калькою з російської, вони просто походять від одного і того ж праслов'янського слова.